# Want to place a warning trigger before deleting row from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to place a warning before deleting a specific row from mysql using php, here's my code please suggest me how should I do it?? The delete script is working perfectly.

this is my **users-delete.php**

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php"); ?>
<?php

 if ($_SESSION["isadmin"])
{

$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$accountid=$_GET["id"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE (id='".$accountid."')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $id=$row['id'];
   $firstname = $row['firstname'];
   $lastname = $row['lastname'];
   $password = $row['password'];
   $email=$row['email'];
   $type=$row['type'];
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Delete User</title>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="../admin/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<?php include("../admin/includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php include("../admin/includes/nav.php"); ?>
<?php include("../admin/includes/manage-users-aside.php"); ?>
<div id="maincontent">

<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="">Home</a> >
     <a href="">Manage Users</a> >
     <a href="">List Users</a> >
     Delete User
</div>
<h2>Delete User</h2>

<form method="post" action="users-delete-action.php">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $accountid; ?>" name="id" />
<label>Email/Username:</label><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;     ?>" /><br /><br />
<label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo   $password;?>" /><br /><br />
<label>First Name:</label><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo   $firstname; ?>" /><br /><br />
<label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo  $lastname; ?>" /><br /><br />
<label>Type:</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="S" <?php if ($type == 'S') echo   'checked="checked"'; ?> />Student<br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="T" <?php if ($type == 'T') echo  'checked="checked"'; ?> /> Teacher<br />

    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>



</div>

</body>
<?php include("../admin/includes/footer.php"); ?>
</html>
<?php
}
else
{
    header("Location: ".$fullpath."login/unauthorized.php");

}
?>
```

this is   users-delete-action.php

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php");?>
<?php

$id=$_POST["id"];
$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("ombts", $con);
$query=("DELETE FROM accounts WHERE id='".$id."'");
$result=mysql_query($query);
 if($result){
echo "User has been Deleted Successfully!!";
}mysql_close($con);
?>
```

please help, I'll be grateful :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 solution would be just to modify the form :

```
    <form name="form" method="post" action="users-delete-action.php">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $accountid; ?>" name="id" />
<label>Email/Username:</label><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;     ?>" /><br /><br />
<label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo   $password;?>" /><br /><br />
<label>First Name:</label><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo   $firstname; ?>" /><br /><br />
<label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo  $lastname; ?>" /><br /><br />
<label>Type:</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="S" <?php if ($type == 'S') echo   'checked="checked"'; ?> />Student<br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="T" <?php if ($type == 'T') echo  'checked="checked"'; ?> /> Teacher<br />

    <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?')) document.form.submit(); return false;">" /> </form>​
```

ATTENTION :

The method you are using to delete is VERY UNSAFE. If someone sues firebug to edit the hidden input he can delete anyone !

EDIT : Fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/M7fG2/

Comment: if that not a good way to place this warning..what else should i do to prevent that danger?? the code u told above is a javascript?? i never used java script...i am sorry but where should i use    document.forms["form"].submit();    ????

Comment: `document.forms["form"].submit();` is inside the onClick event - `onClick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ?')) document.forms["form"].submit(); return false;">"`

Comment: I put an example of the working code in fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/M7fG2/ you can check the code there

Comment: Best way is to leave the client validation ( the alert ) and to a second check within the php and don't send the ID in the hidden form. It is not elegant, but you can store the variable in the $_SESSION global. Instead of `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $accountid; ?>" name="id" />` use in php `$_SESSION['id'] = $accountid` and when you delete, read the id from `$_SESSION['id']`.

Answer (score 2):

Attach confirm on submit

```
<form method="post" action="users-delete-action.php" 
 onsubmit="return confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete?");">
```

Answer (score 1):

use this on submit button :

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirmSubmit()" />
```

Comment: i've used it just like you told but its not working..i mean its dleting user without any warnings..

Comment: you should check for javascript is working or not on your page.

Comment: yup javascript is not working yet, im just using php, isnt there any way to use warning thru php??